# How to avoid duplicate menu buttons in devices with API>10

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

How can I remove or hide the soft menu button in the bottom bar but still keep the overflow menu button in the `ActionBar`. 
I have set the target API to:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="11"
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679876/how-do-i-control-the-soft-menu-button-in-honeycomb).

My app does have menu items so I am overriding the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.
The menu button appears both in the right side of the `ActionBar` and in a bottom bar. I simple don't want the space in the bottom of screen to be wasted for a duplicate menu button. I have seen apps like YouTube or Google Play which only have menu button in the `ActionBar` so I assume there should be a way to do this.

Comment: Try raising your `android:targetSdkVersion` to `14`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html

Comment: thanks. it works with with 14. but what should be done with HoneyComb devices?

Comment: It will have the same effect on Honeycomb devices, as 14 is higher than 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raising target API to 14 `(android:targetSdkVersion="14")` solved this problem.
with thanks to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)
`